# NetSuite Can you order User Event Scipts

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am working on an instance of NetSuite that has multiple user event scripts connected to transactions. I am running into problems where they are running in the wrong sequence and causing failure of processes to get done. This happened I think because there are both SS2 and SS1 scripts that were created over time and were no combined and or they didn't have the budget to rewrite. Is there any way to order the scripts or would using a workflow to trigger the scripts perhaps?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to the Customization > Scripting > Scripted Records then select the record where the scripts are deployed.  In that page, you can set the order of execution of your user event scripts.

Comment: Completely awesome, done in one! that is great, thanks very much

Comment: Is it top down meaning the first one runs first?